# multiple definition of `something'

Tags: c, multiple-definition-error

In "my_header.h" I defined

```
FILE *f;
char *logfile = "my_output.txt";
#define OPEN_LOG     f = fopen(logfile, "a")
#define CLOSE_LOG    fclose(f)
```

and in "my_source.c", I used it in this way

```
#include "my_header.h"
....
OPEN_LOG;
fprintf(f, "some strings\n");
CLOSE_LOG;
```

However the linker says

```
my_source.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `logfile'
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5):

As always, don't define variables in your header file.  Because every time you `#include` that header file, that variable will be re-defined (remember that `#include` == "copy and paste", effectively), leading to the linker error that you're seeing.

Comment: So what should I do? I defined them in a header file so that I can use them in more than one .c file.

Comment: @mahmood: Why not just write functions, rather than this macro solution?  Then you wouldn't need variables exposed to the outside world.

Comment: That is also possible. However I want to log somethings in multiple source files. They all should be written in one log file. So I decided to create a global variable and define some macros.  why not using macro?

Comment: @mahmood: Ok, but why don't you just create a centralised `logging.c`, that exposes the various logging functions?  Then all of your other source files can just access these functions.

Comment: @mahmood: Also, to see the problem with macros, consider what happens if you have `void func1() { OPEN_LOG; func2(); CLOSE_LOG } ... void func2() { OPEN_LOG; ... CLOSE_LOG; }`.  This quickly becomes a mess.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a new file (`my_stuff.c`), and have this in there:

```
char *logfile = "my_output.txt";
```

The .c file **defines** the variable. Then change the header to have this instead of the definition:

```
extern char *logfile;
```

This makes it a **declaration**. Now things should work, but you have to compile the extra module, and include it in the link phase. (Details of doing that depend on your development tools.)